# Unicode-string mismatch issue while updating the records in mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, unicode

In mongo I am storing list which contains dictionary. 
something like `[{"a": 1, "city" : "pune"}, {"b": 2, "city" : "abad"}]`.

When I update this list with new list, some dict are new and some old. So it should store only distinct dictionaries. For that what I do is, fetch existing record from mongo, and append new dictionary.

```
record['result'].extend([k for k in new_key if k not in record['result']])
```

This line create distinct dictionary in `record['result']`.

Dictionary in input `record` comes as string, but dict which fetched from mongo comes as `unicode`, So to avoid mismatch I convert fetched mongo record in string.

```
record['result'].extend([k for k in new_key if k not in record['result']])
```

Code:

```
def saveEntity(self, record):
    try:
        self.collection.insert(record)
        print "mongo done"
    except Exception:
        print 'Failed to save value '
        data = self.collection.find({'date': 2})
        new_key = []
        for key in data:
            for val in key['result']:
                new_key.append({ str(key):str(value) for key,value in val.items() })
            record['result'].extend([k for k in new_key if k not in record['result']])
        self.collection.update(
                {'date' : 2},
               { '$set' : {'result': record['result']}},
               True
        )

result = {'date': 2, 'result' : [{"a": 1, "city" : "pune"}, {"b": 2, "city" : "abad"}]}
#result = {'date': 2, 'result' : [{"a": 1, "city" : "pune"}, {"c": 3, "city" : "mum"}]}
YoutubeTrend().saveEntity(result)
```

But still records stored in mongodb are not distinct. Anyone can help?

**Update**
Suppose input list is,

```
[{"a": 1, "city" : "pune"}, {"b": 2, "city" : "abad"}]
```

list fetched from mongo which takes all values in unicode format

```
[{"a": 1, "city" : "pune"}, {"c": 3, "city" : "mum"}]
```

Updated list in mongo should looks like

```
[{"a": 1, "city" : "pune"}, {"b": 2, "city" : "abad"}, {"c": 3, "city" : "mum"}]
```

Comment: could you be a little more clear

Comment: @VigneshKalai: could you please check it again

Comment: so you want your result to be like `{ "a":1,"b":2,"city":["pune","abad"]}`

Comment: @VigneshKalai: I dont want to change the dict, I want all dictionaries in the list should be distincts. Please check my update